# How to store echo in a variable in PHP without duplicating?

Tags: php

Imagine the following:

```
<?php
echo 'foo';
echo 'bar';
?>
```

Simple, right? Now, what if at the end of this simple script I need to have everything I've echoed in that script in a variable, like:

```
<?php
echo 'foo';
echo 'bar';
// $end // which contains 'foobar';
?>
```

I tried this:

```
<?php
$end = NULL;
echo $end .= 'foo'; // this echoes foo
echo $end .= 'bar'; // this echoes foobar (this is bad)
// $end // which contains 'foobar' (this is ok);
?>
```

But it doesn't work, as it appends the data, therefore echoes the appended data (duplicated). Any way to do this?

**EDIT:** I cannot use OB, as I'm already using it in the script in a different way (I'm simulating a CLI-output in a browser).

Comment: Why wont you create a function that echoes and appends the output?

Comment: Output buffering can be nested

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was misunderstanding: so then I'd suggest this:

```
<?php
    $somevar = '';
    function record_and_echo($msg,$record_var) {
        echo($msg);
        return ($msg);
    }
    $somevar .= record_and_echo('foo');
    //...whatever else//
    $somevar .= record_and_echo('bar');
?>
```

old:
Unless I'm misunderstanding this'll do that fine:

```
<?php
    $output = ''
    $output .= 'foo';
    $output .= 'bar';
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: This isn't what he wants to do, he wants to concatenate 'foo' and 'bar' in  $end, but in the second echo display just 'bar'

Comment: hmm yes on re-reading I see what you mean @Amine; see my edit.

Comment: Yeah, this is a better answer ! But... the function takes 2 parameters, and the second one isn't used... ?!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish, but consider output buffering:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "foo";
echo "bar";

$end = ob_get_clean();
echo $end;
```

Comment: I cannot use OB, as I'm already using it in the script in a different way (I'm simulating a CLI-output in a browser).

Comment: @RichardRodriguez Output buffering can be nested.

Answer (score 0):

OB can be nested:

```
<?php
ob_start();

echo 'some output';

ob_start();

echo 'foo';
echo 'bar';

$nestedOb = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo 'other output';

$outerOb = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo 'Outer output: ' . $outerOb . '' . "\n" . 'Nested output: ' . $nestedOb;
```

The result:

```
Outer output: some outputother output;
Nested output: foobar
```